# How to get id of element when user select the item from ListView

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

To go to the album menu, I need to determine which artist the user has chosen. But I can't figure out how to read the element id from the Firestore after the user clicked on the element. For example, there is artist_1 and artist_2, the user clicks on artist_1 and gets his id, after which this id can be used to get information about albums. With my code, the id of the last element is written to the document_id variable, even if i've chosen the first artist. Please help me figure it out.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/screens/songspage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/screens/albums.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<Home> {
  CollectionReference _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist');

var artist_id, album_id, song_id;
Future getArtists() async {
QuerySnapshot on = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("artist").get();
var documentID;
for (var snapshot in on.docs) {
  documentID = snapshot.id; // <-- Document ID
}
print(documentID);
return on.docs;
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getArtists(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlbumWidget(
))),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data[index]["name"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    elevation: 10.0,
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the id in the `arguments` property which is available with `Navigator`. You can use `Navigator.pushNamed` like so.

```
return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/albums',
                                arguments: snapshot.data[index]["id"],
                         );
                  child: Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data[index]["name"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    elevation: 10.0,
                  ),
                );
```

Now in the `AlbumWidget` , you can create a final variable `id` and access it using `widget.` property.

```
class AlbumWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? id;
  const AlbumWidget(this.id, {super.key});

  @override
  State<AlbumWidget> createState() => _AlbumWidgetState();
}

class _AlbumWidgetState extends State<AlbumWidget> {
  String? id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     id=widget.id;
  }

  @override
  // rest of the code here
```

Similarly, if you want the whole album data, just pass the index like so:

`arguments: snapshot.data[index]`

Depending upon the argument's data type, create a variable in the `AlbumWidget` and access it using `widget.`

Comment: I've tried it, but i've got a Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform error

Comment: You can use ```.then()``` and get the data once the value is there.

Comment: And return the list view inside ```if(snapshot.hasData){}```